# What factors determine whether militia will assist in a battle?

Tags: endless-legend

In Endless Legend, the militia units can provide some additional military power when countering a monster attack or invasion from another faction.

However it's difficult to determine how far and when they will help in a battle.  I've seen militias from 2 cities participate in an attack, while in another game I've been unable to get the militias to provide assistance in a relatively close battle.
It seems like tech, buildings, population, or movement may have an impact on the militias assistance range, but its not precisely clear what or how militia assistance is determined.

I found this quote on an [wiki article about battles](http://endless-legend.wikia.com/wiki/Battles):

> The Militia is a group of units generated by a City. They can only be
>   used when a battle takes place and overlaps the city they are in. They
>   can be improved by various research technologies.

But I have seen multiple battles with the city in the center of the battle where the militia does not help.(is this a bug?)

How far and in what situations will militia participate in a battle?

Comment: It has something to do with the attacking army as well. If given the choice of attacking an army coming to break my siege or letting them attack me, I let them attack me to avoid pulling city militia. I am about 75% sure this works but I haven't double-checked. Also often the city militia have died, and haven't been replenished yet.

Comment: Militia can only participate in one battle per turn, just like other units. Sometimes they don't participate because of this.

Comment: @DCShannon Hmm, if you feel like make an answer out of that, I will select it.

Comment: @MarkRogers Thanks, but I don't think that's complete enough to be a whole answer. If someone puts together some information on the range of their involvement and how being attacked or attacking affects things, then that would be a good note to add.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you right-click an enemy army to attack them, **before** you release the right mouse button, you get an overlay of where the battlefield will be.

This could be tactically important if you e.g. need to keep the high ground or wish to engage them from a direction that suits you best.

If a city falls in the designated battlefield tiles, its militia will join the fight.

As was mentioned in the comments, you need to have militia ready, that have not already fought this turn.